# AWS SSL Certs across domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an AWS certificate in us-west-2 and an elasticbeanstalk app in us-east-1. It seems I cannot apply the cert to the app, presumably because it is cross-region.

How should I proceed? Should I generate a second certificate? Or can I make it available to the app somehow?

Answer (score 1):

> To use a certificate with Elastic Load Balancing for the same fully qualified domain name (FQDN) or set of FQDNs in more than one AWS region, you must request or import a certificate for each region.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-regions.html